# R: Return ids where no entries for row match criteria

Tags: r

This seems like a fairly simple operation but I can't figure out how to do it or search for it.

I have data similar to the following:

```
id,status
123,0
123,1
124,1
125,1
125,2
126,0
126,2
```

I want a list of ids that don't have any rows where the status is 2. So in the example above, the operation would return:

```
123
124
```

I believe that in sql it might be something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM user
WHERE id NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM user
WHERE status='2')
)
```

But I'm not sure how to do that in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put it into a data.table:

```
require(data.table)
mydt <- data.table(user)
```

Then the syntax works like this:

```
mydt[
  ,
  list(keep=all(status!=2)),
by=id][
  (keep),
  id
]
```

That is, `FROM[WHERE,SELECT,BY][WHERE2,SELECT2,BY2]...[WHEREK,SELECTK,BYK]`. After each set of brackets, you have a new data.table to work with for the next query in the chain.

After you install the `data.table` package, you can type `vignette("datatable-faq")` and browse to question 2.16 for details on the analogy between SQL syntax and what's available in data.table.